# PHP: Problem with strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

What's going on with strtotime here?

```
$today = date('m.d.y H:i', time());
echo strtotime($today);
```

It does not output anything... What's going on?

Comment: `m.d.y` is an ambiguous date format. Try `Y-m-d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtotime` can only parse [certain formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), not *any* random assortment of numbers and letters. "m.d.y H:i" is not a format `strtotime` can parse. You'll need to parse that manually using, for example, [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/strptime).

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime::createFromFormat() if you know source format of date ('m.d.y H:i') in your example

```
print DateTime::createFromFormat('m.d.y H:i',$date)->getTimestamp()
```

**Manual**
[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
[DateTime::getTimestamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` works with US dates.  Try

```
$today = date('m/d/y H:i', time());
echo strtotime($today);
```

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() is a function for formatting the date, before it is outputted. It seems like the date is already formated in the date() function, and that you make no attempt to format the date in the second line.

**Correct code**

```
$today = date("Y-m-d-H.i");
$datenumber = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($today));
$timenumber = date('H.i',strtotime($today));
```

You can echo all those variables.

Comment: `strtotime` is a function for turning a string into a timestamp. `date` does the reverse and turns a timestamp into a string.

Comment: I don't use timestamps ever with php, and insert all dates and times into a mysql database as a VARCHAR string and not has a TIME timestamp. You're right. I didn't know that. For me, `date` is for specifying a date format, and `strtotime` is for changing the format of an outputted date, or moving a date forward or backward in time by a specified time period.

Comment: If you've ever used `strtotime` or have ever added a number to a time, you have used timestamps. :o)