# php fgetcsv read date in different format

Tags: codeigniter, fgetcsv

In csv cell contain date in format `31-Mar-90`. Now If that csv created on Windows + MS Excel 2007, my php scripts shows in same format ie: `31-Mar-90` but if same date format added in csv that created on some other platform then php shows like: `31 Mar 1990`

script is

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { //Reading the file
       $num = count($data);    
       for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
           $csvData[$row][$c] = $data[$c];
       }    
       $row++;
   }            
   fclose($handle);
}
var_debug($csvData);
```

and once I open & save csv (created in other platform) in Windows MS-Excel 2007, php outputs `31-Mar-90` which is my requirement.

Here is csv: [image]

Comment: Hi, I made an update in the answer, beware of the strtotime and validate the input, or you'll have headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever trust the input, just transform the date to timestamp and then apply the format you wish:

```
$csvData[$row][$c] = date('d-M-Y', strtotime( $data[$c] ) );
```

Or if you don't like the transform, validate the input and throw an error if you don't like the date format.

Check http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

### UPDATE

I forgot to mention: beware of the strtotime transformation, it has its own rules:

[PHP: Problem with strtotime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919478/php-problem-with-strtotime)

[Strtotime() doesn't work with dd/mm/YYYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format)

So, better validate always the input, and then, apply the time transform